# Error with UPDATE query not updating my MySql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass an array of data to a Update query, to update customer records. However for some reason the ?success page is showing saying my details have been updated, however they aren't. If I debug and echo

```
echo implode(', ', $update);
die();
```

I get the result

> `mem_first_name` = 'Josh', `mem_last_name` = 'smith', `mem_email` = 'j.smith@gmail.com', `allow_email` = '0'

Which looks fine to me. This is my update_user function

```
function update_user($mem_id, $update_data) {
$update = array();
array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

foreach ($update_data as $field=>$data) {
    $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
}

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id` = '$mem_id'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

And my $update_data array

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
$message = 'Your details have been updated';
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

    $update_data = array(
            'mem_first_name' => $_POST['mem_first_name'],
            'mem_last_name' => $_POST['mem_last_name'],
            'mem_email' => $_POST['mem_email'],
            'allow_email' => ($_POST['allow_email']) ? 1 : 0
    );

    update_user($session_member_id, $update_data);
    header('Location: settings.php?success');
    exit();
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    $message = output_errors($errors);
}
}
```

So I have worked out I am losing my backticks after I implode, thus the column names don't have back ticks

Comment: Executing the query from terminal works?

Comment: What is the output of the whole query before it is executed?

Comment: better if u can print Query before execution line ?

Comment: Your success page is showing true , because the function update_user does not checks whether the query got executed or not! Try to echo the query that is going to be executed, and run it in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of typo (and thus not a real question of course).
You are adding backticks to your fields

```
$update[] = '`' . $field . '`
             ^   here
```

But they are absent in the debug out.
So, you are either run or post wrong code, which makes whole question pointless.

Comment: I've run all of the above and not changed anything. I'm not sure why this back tick isn't showing above my column names

Comment: If I print_r($update) I get the backticks, however once I implode I lose them

Answer (score 0):

check connection with db, and table field name spells., i think no problem in this code.

Comment: I am losing the back ticks once I implode so the column names aren't showing as field names